# Difficult to find an app published to the Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an App to the google play store a couple months ago but I cannot seem to get any downloads. My question is, does google put a block where your app is hard to search for if it is your first app, such as to prevent spammers. I can only seem to find it when I type in my developer name "ajk4550"

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=edu.roberts.kaye_aaron.BibleVerse

Even searching Bible Verse Viewer it does not show up at all. Is there any tips for getting your app to show up when searching? I have even added this to the bottom:

Keywords: Bible, bible, Verse, verse, Viewer, viewer, christian, religious. I know it is live and working because I've downloaded it from the store on my phone. Any tips? Is there anything google does to make it harder?

Comment: They do not that I know of. They do, however, bump popular and highly rated apps. You'd be surprised the marketing a lot of apps out there put in to being successful.

Comment: Oh ok, so as you get more downloads and better ratings it becomes higher on the search results?

Comment: Also you should remove your keywords from the app description as it is against the Google Play Policy https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2985717

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I removed it so it will be updated soon.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, it is saying that your app is incompatible with all of my devices (e.g. not compatible for Nexus 5?  not compatible for Nexus 7? Seems odd).  I suspect that Google will not show results for apps which are not compatible with my devices.  If I am representative (and the 7 or so devices I have associated with my account are a fairly representative sample of "average" devices) that could go some way to help explain it.

There is also a lot of competition there for similar sounding apps with similar search terms. As others have commented, it seems that apps with high ratings and downloads appear first.  You may need to do some marketing to promote it further to get some activity going.